# Entity Framework doesn't create Context and table classes(.cs) from Entity Data Model (from existing database) in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-6

I have an ASP.Net MVC Project and Existing database.When I add new item -> ADO.Net Entity Data Model, it gives me the model (Model1.edmx including 4 files in it `Model1.Context.tt`,`Model1.Designer.cs`,`Model1.edmx.diagram`,`Model1.tt`)
but it doesn't create my .cs files and DbContext file. When I click Update Model From Database it gives me two errors:

```
"CompanyProject\Models\Model1.Context.tt.
Error message is The custom tool 'TextTemplatingFileGenerator' failed."
CompanyProject\Models\Model1.tt.
Error message is The custom tool 'TextTemplatingFileGenerator' failed.**
```

Can you help me?

Comment: Welcome to SO ;) Please read this article on [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). This would include a proper description of what you are trying to achieve, your code (or the relevant snippets) as well as your efforts showing what you have tried so far and possible error messages. It is also advisable to provide a full [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it by doing:
Change the Custom Tool property : .edmx Properties -> Advanced -> Custom Tool:TextTemplatingFileGenerator

Answer (score -1):

I ran into this problem some day ago, and I fixed it by doing:

Right click on .Context.tt file -> run custom tool, try it many time and before retry build and clean your project

Hope this help.

Leo

Comment: I tried but , it gave me this error :[image](https://i.ibb.co/pwX62Vb/mvcError.png)

Comment: @Semih Try the same thing by right click on .edmx and run the same command (run custom tool)

Comment: @Semih well, the only thing that remain is delete your .edmx and the connection string on web.config, clean your project and create a new .edmx

Comment: I fixed it by changing Custom tool in properties of .edmx. Thank you!